# Customise github actions workflow by selecting specific cron schedule

Tags: github-actions

I have set up two jobs running on github actions in one single `.yaml` file. Yet, they are required to be run on different frequency, one bi-weekly and another one once in every  six months. I have googled and found out that I should use an `if` block to check cron-schedule before running and made the following code.

However, under this case, I would not be able to re-run both jobs on job update automatically, as they are now blocked by the cron schedule checking step. Is there any way I can get pass that?

```
name:Sample
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/xx.yml
  schedule:
    - cron: "30 10 6,20 * *"
    - cron: "00 19 15 */6 *"

jobs: 
    first_job:
    if: github.event.schedule == "30 10 6,20 * *"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    run: echo "Happy Day"
    
    second_job:
    if: github.event.schedule == "00 19 15 */6 *"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    run: echo "Nice Coding"
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't separate the jobs / triggers in 2 different workflows / `.yaml` files?

Comment: Both jobs are using the same set-up and same goal destination output. So it is natural to put them in one `.yaml` file

Comment: You could also use a reusable workflow in that case, and each workflow could use the same one.